# WordPress site - Home page link triggering a download rather then opening the home page

Tags: wordpress

A website I built triggers a download instead of opening the home page when the home page link is clicked.

The site is built in WordPress and up until today has worked absolutely fine.

I can log into WordPress and I can access all the other pages.  It is just the home page which is causing the issue.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Thanks for your time and help with this.

Comment: Look in the .htaccess file; a plugin could be causing this; if it's a bad template the template itself could be causing this; if it's bad hosting there could be a configuration setting in the wrong place like php.ini, httpd.conf; check on other devices, it might be a cache setting on your current device. Look in the error logs. For now I'm out of ideas. Hard to tell without further information.

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance, rename the file called .htaccess in the web root folder of your site and try. If that works, you will need to find and edit/remove some code in there. (Can't tell what in absence of the contents of the file.)

If that doesn't work, disable all plugins and try. If that works, keep enabling one plugin at a time and checking, until you find the culprit. (Then, delete and reinstall it).

If that doesn't work, temporarily activate some other theme and try. If that works, delete and re-install the theme. (Caution: this may cause the loss of any/all theme settings and customization, so proceed with care.)

If none of the above works, there is almost certainly something wrong with your server/php config which can't be identified in absence of the the contents of those files.